# CakePHP 2.x SparkPost Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x, sparkpost

I was developing one web application in cakephp 2.2.3. that application I was using CakeEmail. But Now I want to implement SparkPost plugin for email deliver.

I spend lots of time in google but not getting any satisfied result. All are code I found cakephp 3.0 or higher.

Below I have posted some links for cakephp 3.x -

https://github.com/syntaxera/cakephp-sparkpost-plugin

https://github.com/narendravaghela/cakephp-sparkpost

Please help me and give me any idea about to implement sparkpost in cakephp 2.x.

Answer (score 5):

[SparkPost supports SMTP](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/smtp-api) so you could [configure CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) for that.  Here's a (guessed-at) configuration stanza:

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $sparkpost = array(
        'host' => 'smtp.sparkpostmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'username' => 'SMTP_Injection',
        'password' => 'YOUR_API_KEY_WITH_SMTP_PRIVILEGES',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => true
    );
}
```

Then in your controller code, you would instantiate a `CakeEmail` instance using the config stanza named above:

```
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->config('sparkpost');
$email->from(...)->to(...)->subject(...)->send();
```